# Implementing sum (i=0 to k) of X^i * Y in CUDA C

Tags: c, cuda

I'm looking for tips or research papers that will help me perform the sum (i=0 to k) of X^i * Y, or more explicitly, Y + X^1 * Y +...+ X^k * Y in CUDA C. Where X is an N-by-N matrix, and Y is a N-by-1 vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [Thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/).

Factor out the Y, then just do a scan (using multiplication as the operator) followed by a reduction (using addition as the operator).

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't what you're looking for, but can't you factor the Y out and just right multiply it with the result of sum(i=0 to k) of X^i?

Comment: You're right, I could and should do that; my focus of the question was really about implementing sum(i=0 to k) of X^i.

Answer (score 1):

Besides factoring out `Y` from the summation, you could compute the eigenspace of `X` and subsequently very efficiently compute each `X^i` (the slowest part of computing your summation will undoubtedly be raising `X` to a range of powers, so I'll attack that).

More specifically, compute the eigenvalues of `X` and form a diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues, call this `Q`. Using the eigenvalues, we can diagonalize `X` and create a new matrix `D` such that

```
(1)    D = Q^-1 X Q
```

Because `D` is diagonal, we can very efficiently compute it raised to any power `i`. Applying (1) we determine that

```
(2)    D^i = (Q^-1 X Q)^i
```

and furthermore, we can show that (2) is equivalent to

```
(3)    D^i = Q^-1 X^i Q
```

Finally, we can find any arbitrary `X^i` efficiently by rearranging our equation and computing

```
(4)    X^i = Q D^i Q^-1
```

(I wanted to verify my memory here, so I found a [reference on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#An_application)).

Comment: E, Thank you for your solution; however, you assume too much information about X. Elements of X, and for the matter of completeness Y, can be any real value. So since you can't diagonalizable every matrix, I'm unable to use this solution.

Comment: @Anon, there's no one-size-fits-all solution to doing this fast.  If your matrix cannot be diagonalized then this cannot be applied, but when it can be applied it will outperform repeatedly multiplying the matrix.